# pgAdmin4 KeyError: 'ck_port_range'

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

When running pgAdmin4, `The pgAdmin 4 server could not be contacted` error occurs with following log .

```
2023-07-24 10:59:36,375: ERROR  pgadmin:    Database migration failed

2023-07-24 10:59:36,380: ERROR  pgadmin:    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\pgAdmin 4\v7\python\lib\site-packages\alembic\operations\batch.py", line 692, in drop_constraint
    const = self.named_constraints.pop(const.name)
KeyError: 'ck_port_range'

...

PermissionError: [WinError 32] �ٸ� ���μ����� ������ ��� ���̱� ������ ���μ����� �׼��� �� �� �����ϴ�: 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Roaming\\pgAdmin\\pgadmin4.db' -> 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Roaming\\pgAdmin\\pgadmin4.db.20230724105936'
```

If anyone knows anything about this error, I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: It would be helpful for future readers of your question if you add some context information, like the concerned pgAdmin version and your OS. Note, that people might find your question years later.

Comment: Please report this to https://github.com/pgadmin-org/pgadmin4/issues

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem with pgAdmin4 version 7.5 on a Windows 10 machine where an old version 4.11 was installed (by central company installation) and without a local PostgreSQL database.

Replacing version 7.5 by 6.21 (the latest and only available v6) gave me the hint that the internal pgAdmin4 database in `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\pgadmin\` was corrupted. I deleted the whole folder and then 6.21 ran without problems. **Note, that all configuration was reset by that.**

Then I installed the current version 7.5, which also ran without problems, and deinstalled the 6.21 after that.

I assume that it would have been sufficient to only delete the `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\pgadmin\` folder in the first place to solve the problem.

Comment: Running pgAdmin4 7.3, simply deleting the pgadmin folder contents was sufficient for me